# Finding degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{3}}) : \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

This is question 12 from chapter 6 in Stewart's *Galois Theory*. The hint is to first show that the adjoined element is not a square in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$. That's easy. See the rest in the comments.

Comment: Well, the degree of the extension is *at most* four, since $$r=\sqrt{1+\sqrt3}\implies r^2=1+\sqrt3=\implies r^4-2r^2+1-3=0$$ and thus $\;\sqrt{1+\sqrt3}\;$ is a root of a quartic...

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Now I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{3}}$. Since $(\alpha^2-1)^2 = 3$,
$$ q(x) = x^4-2x^2-2 $$
is an element of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ that vanishes at $x=\alpha$. We just need to prove that such a polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ to have that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{3}}):\mathbb{Q}=4$ as expected. But $q(x)$, for instance, is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_7$, since in $\mathbb{F}_7[x]$
$$ x^7-1\pmod{x^4-2x^2-2}=-(x^3+3x+1)\\ x^{49}-1\pmod{x^4-2x^2-2}=-(x+1). $$
As an alternative, we may just apply Eisenstein criterion with $p=2$ as suggested by DonAntonio to have that $q(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: How could easily be checked the polynomial is irreducible over $\;\Bbb F_7\;$ ? Or how could that be checked in an *easier* way than over the rationals? Anyway, Eisenstein's Test solves this at once with $\;p=2\;$ .

Answer (score 1):

I think the book has this 
$$[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=2\cdot 2$$ in mind.

Comment: But the crucial part is still hidden here: why $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{3}}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})=2$?

Comment: As OP has remarked $1+\sqrt{3}$ is not a perfect square in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$. So the extension is adding a square root to this field, that always has degree $2$, if it is a proper extension.

Comment: Indeed, since the Norm of $1+\sqrt3$ is $-2$, the number $1+\sqrt3$ is a prime (irreducible) element.